# Outlook Ribbon(Xml) and Ribbon(Visual Designer) not working in same project

Tags: c#, xml, outlook

I am creating outlook add-in in that I have context menu and task pane and a Ribbon button. I have created context menu using `Ribbon(Xml)` control.

Now I want to create a Ribbon toggle button for showing or hiding the task pane. I have find the code for showing or hiding the task pane [from this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb608590.aspx).

Now I have added that `Ribbon(Visual designer)` in my project but it is not working.

When I Use `Ribbon(Xml)` or `Ribbon(Visual Designer)` both in same project than Xml ribbon works but visual designer not working.

So my question is. **How can I use both Ribbons in the same project?**

Any help will be appreciated.